# How to send text to an address (with Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to have a button on a page that sends text to a server different from where the page is being served from. The server I want to send to is not running an apache/php/cgi/php-etc-etc server, so I just want to send text to it.

Is that even possible? I have looked all over, but everything I have found has to do with an html document being sent to a client, and the client script sending the modified url or the document back to a server that reads html/php, etc. Is it possible to send arbitrary strings to arbitrary addresses?

Update:

The server on the other end parses configuration for a device it controls. I know exactly what text I want to send it. It's just that I have been asked to provide a web-interface to the server, and I can't put any kind of traditional web server on it. However, it can send (vetted) files to anyone who establishes it's style of connection. What I thought of was having it send clients a webpage they could view locally to generate configurations and send back to it. But I'm having trouble doing that because the server cannot respond to traditional scripting facilities.

That, in my mind, equates to needing to convince a browser to emit text at a socket.

Comment: What is the point of sending text to arbitrary adresses if they won't do anything with this information? You should elaborate on this.

Comment: I tried to clarify things. I want to send bytes to an address from a browser. That is my goal. I elaborated on it by editing my post.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible if you know there API. Lets say you want to send data to `Tumblr.`.

You must know there API and how they get the data and use it. Then you can send the data from your page to their link using javascript or jQuery (if you like). And yes, you will be using QueryStrings to be sent to the server so that they use that string to save and process the data.

I am not sure what type of server that might be, but if it accepts a QueryString then if can process any type of data that is provided and save it accordingly.

So the answer would be that you must first create an API on the second server which would be used to send the data accordingly by the first server where the data is present. Using JavaScript or any other Server Side language to redirect the user.

Comment: Yes, I know the API on the other end. The problem is that there is not an Apache server or whatever to interpret traditional scripting interaction. So I can't "navigate" to the address, wait of PHP/Ajax/ActiveX/CGI/ to connect, and "post" "forms". What I have is a socket and a text stream I need to send it.